# Maven: rebuild jar

Tags: java, android, maven, jar

I want to use a jar as a library for an Android project. I need to change java version and rebuild it. Which are the correct steps of doing so??
Jar is built with maven
Inside the jar:

```
META-INF
   maven/project
       >pom.properties
       >pom.xml
   >MANIFEST.MF
project
    directory1
       >class files
    directory2
      >class files
```

If there are dependencies, how should I treat those?

Comment: Don't you have the sources of the library?

Comment: @Tunaki, Yes I also have the sources

Comment: Then why do you want to rebuild the jar? If you have the source, make the modifications in it and launch Maven to build it.

Comment: I just noticed that now, thanks! Is this site enough for me to understand maven bulid? http://maven.apache.org/archives/maven-1.x/start/concepts.html

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the documentation of Maven to understand how things work. Your link is Maven 1 which is pretty outdated, Maven 3 is the latest. If you hit a specific problem and can't find an answer, come back here and ask a question.